# Does setInterval wait for the action inside if it is blocking?

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

Hello I have a function as below

```js
let schedule = setInterval(() => {
    result = execSync(command).toString()
}, 2000)
```

1. if execSync takes more than 2000 to resolve, would setInterval still repeat or will by being **synchronous**, **execSync** will make **setInterval** to wait for it to finish first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of both:

If `execSync` takes 2000ms, it means that **no other code** will run during those 2 seconds. After all, JavaScript is single-threaded, and you're blocking that thread.

After `execSync` finished (and the function call it's in finishes), the event loop just continues. Since 2s have already passed since the last time the interval happened, the next call will happen nearly instantly.

You can quickly validate this yourself (e.g. in the REPL):

```js
execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
setInterval(() => { console.log('a', Date.now()); execSync('sleep 2'); console.log('b', Date.now()); }, 2000);
```

Also interesting to know: if you sleep for 5s instead, the result will be the same (if you ignore the freezes being longer). As in, after `execSync` finishes, it won't suddenly trigger two tasks at once. Validation:

```js
execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
i = 0;
setInterval(() => { console.log('a', Date.now()); if (i++ > 5) return; execSync('sleep 5'); console.log('b', Date.now()); }, 2000)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for clarifying, I'm asking because my electron app always froze up(not responding) so I thought the setInterval() was executing multiple times when the command takes long but now that's not the case, I rewrote it to use setTimeOut() instead and execute command Asynchronously to make sure the command finishes first and it does not froze up anymore, would you happen to know why it was freezing up in the first case with setInterval? Is it because its is blocking the thread and Window thinks that's a problem?

Comment: Just as in a browser (both when doing an infinite loop or just pausing JS using e.g. breakpoints), freezing will prevent you from interacting with the site. And doing this on Electron "server-side" _might_ even freeze the whole window if it's the render process, I don't really know how Electron works internally.